# How to solve logic problem with a joker sometimes tell truth and sometimes lie?

Tags: boolean-computation, logic

If there are only truth teller and liar, I used to solve with `BooleanConvert` or `SatisfiabilityInstances`. However for this one, how could I use Mathematica to solve?

> Mr. Lee is a senior programmer, but there is something wrong with the three robots he recently designed: the one always tells the truth, the one always lies, and the other sometimes tells the truth, sometimes lies.
> Mr. Lee asked Dr. Gao for help to distinguish them. Dr. Gao took a look and asked 3 questions with them. The questions are shown below:
>
> For the robot on the left side, Dr. Gao: Who is sitting next to you? Robot replied: A truth teller.
>
> For the robot in the middle, Dr. Gao: Who are you? Robot replied: The guy always hesitant.
>
> For the robot on the right side, Dr. Gao: Who is sitting next to you? Robot replied: A liar.
>
> According to the above three question and answers to distinguish these robots.

I also tried `BooleanTable`, since I marked both liar and joker as false. But it seems this way is not general and succinct.

[image: input and output of BooleanTable]

Comment: Is "The guy always hesitant" the same as the joker the same as "sometimes truthful, sometimes not"?

Answer (score 7):

I use `l`, `m`, `r` for the left, middle, right robots respectively. Each can take the values $-1,0,1$ with the following interpretation:

```
truthteller[x_]:=(x==1);
joker[x_]:=(x==0);
liar[x_]:=(x==-1);
```

Using

```
claim[who_,what_]:=And[Implies[truthteller[who],what],
                       Implies[liar[who],Not[what]]];
```

the answers of the three robots are:

```
claims=And[
  claim[l,truthteller[m]],
  claim[m,joker[m]],
  claim[r,liar[m]]
];
```

Our general assumptions are

```
assumptions=And[l!=m!=r, (* no two robots are of same kind *)
                l*(l^2-1)==0,m*(m^2-1)==0,r*(r^2-1)==0 (* only -1,0,1 *) ];
```

We solve using:

```
Reduce[And[claims,assumptions],{l,m,r}]
(* l==0&&m==-1&&r==1 *)
```

From left to right: joker, liar, truthteller.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution from user293787. It is very helpful to me.

After a lot of effort, I also worked out a way myself to solve this.

I define l, m, r as Roberts at left, middle, and right. t as truth-teller, i as liar, and h as hesitater. So, for example, "lt" means the proposition that "left Robert is a truth-teller", "mi" means the proposition that "middle Robert is a liar"

(1) l, m, r each take one role:

```
a = (lt \[And] mh \[And] ri) \[Or] (lt \[And] mi \[And] 
     rh) \[Or] (lh \[And] mt \[And] ri) \[Or] (li \[And] mt \[And] 
     rh) \[Or] ( 
    li \[And] mh \[And] rt) \[Or] (lh \[And] mi \[And] rt);
```

(2) the answers from three roberts:

```
b =  lt \[Implies] mt;
c = mt \[Implies] mh;
d = rt \[Implies] mi;
```

(3) l, m, r each can be only one of the role (no dual roles):

```
e = (lt \[And] \[Not] li \[And] \[Not] lh) \[Or] (\[Not] lt \[And] 
     li \[And] \[Not] lh) \[Or] (\[Not] lt \[And] \[Not] li \[And] lh);
f = (mt \[And] \[Not] mi \[And] \[Not] mh) \[Or] (\[Not] mt \[And] 
     mi \[And] \[Not] mh) \[Or] (\[Not] mt \[And] \[Not] mi \[And] mh);
g = (rt \[And] \[Not] ri \[And] \[Not] rh) \[Or] (\[Not] rt \[And] 
     ri \[And] \[Not] rh) \[Or] (\[Not] rt \[And] \[Not] ri \[And] 
     rh);
```

(4) Use **BooleanConvert**

```
a && b && c && d && e && f && g // BooleanConvert
```

or **SatisfiabilityInstances**

```
SatisfiabilityInstances[
 a && b && c && d && e && f && g, {lt, li, lh, mt, mi, mh, rt, ri, 
  rh}]
```

[image]

To sum up, with **BooleanConvert** or **SatisifiabilityInstances** or **BooleanTable**, it seems every logic problem like this can be solved.